# does python for loop call __len__?

Tags: python, for-loop

Here's the relevant code

```
class f_Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv):
        self.csv = pd.read_csv(csv)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.csv.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = "data/"+self.csv.loc[idx,"File"]
        img = io.imread(path)
        tensorToRet = torch.from_numpy(img)
        label = self.csv.loc[idx,"daysToOvulation"]

        return tensorToRet, label

data = f_data("path/toCSV")

for x,y in data:
    print(x.shape, y)
```

The problem is the loop continues to iterate after the it's passed the last element. I tried putting a print statement in the  **len** function, but it looks like the for loop isn't calling len at all. I can always change it to `for i in range(data):`, but that doesn't seem pythonic.

Why doesn't the loop call **len** and what does it do instead?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is _ _ iter _ _

Comment: I think you mean `range(len(data))`

Comment: @sri the interpreter can use `__len__` and `__getitem__` for iteration if `__iter__` is not provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [loc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to iterate. 
Also the [__len_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) is built-in function called by len() function.

```
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
        'Age': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        } 
# This is dummy data equivalent to what is read by csv

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

for i in range(len(df)) : 
  print(df.loc[i, "Name"], df.loc[i, "Age"])
```